# How to push to an array in an asynchronous operation in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, arraylist, foreach

I am trying to push to an array inside a nested forEach loop in JavaScript yet to no avail. I have tried cloning the array and appending to it but doesn't seem to work for me. below is my code. any help would be hugely appreciated. thanks in advance.

```
const trollImgIds = ["61c25b801957f9eb4f5c2a94", "61c25b801957f9eb4f5c2a95"];
const images:any = [];
trollImgIds.forEach((trollImgId:any) => {
    const imgIds = trollImgId.imgIds;
    imgIds.forEach(async (imgId:any) => {
    const _id = new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(imgId);
    imgGfs.find({ _id: _id }).toArray((err:any, files:any) => {
          if(err){
             console.log(err);
          }
          if(files.length > 0){
              const image:any = [];
              // open download stream and add images to the images array
              const readstream = imgGfs.openDownloadStream(_id);
              // read buffer using stream
              readstream.on('data', (chunk:any) => {
                   image.push(chunk);
              });
              readstream.on('error', () => {
                  console.log('error');
              });
              readstream.on('end', () => {
                 // convert buffer to bufferlist
                 const bufferList = new BufferList(image);
                 // convert the bufferlist to base64 string
                 const base64 = bufferList.toString('base64');
                 // add to images array
                 // console.log("image >>> : ", base64);
                 // clone and add to images array
                 const trollImage = {
                       trollId: trollImgId.id,
                       image: base64
                 }
                 // clone the images array
                 const cloneImages = [...images];
                 // add the troll image to the images array
                 cloneImages.push(trollImage);
                 // set the images array
                  images.push(cloneImages);
            });
         }
      });
  });

});
```

I was expecting to get an output like:

```
images >>> :  [
{
    trollId: new ObjectId("61c25b801957f9eb4f5c2a94"),
    image: '/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAYABgAAD/...'
  }
]
```

which is the case when I log it inside the second forEach loop
however it turns out to be empty outside the loops

Comment: You didn't provide `trollImgIds` and an expected output. No one can understand what you try to achieve.

Comment: It's a hard example of code. You should simplify when exposing a doubt. Try to read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12482961/change-values-in-array-when-doing-foreach):

Comment: What does this mean, please be precise: "_doesn't seem to work for me._"

Comment: What you try to do is push an array in async operation. You may have a look of this question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54100855/pushing-to-an-array-in-async-function-not-working

Comment: Based upon your edit, [this is your issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: Thanks man, works like a charm. I switched to nested for-loop and added a callback function and it worked fine. thanks  brother(s)